# Why is this Python loop running one too many times

Tags: python, string, loops, reverse, cpu-word

i wanna create a Reverse word function, and i tried:

```
def reversa(str):

    j=len(str)
    for i in str:
        j -=1
        print(str[j], end="")


print(reversa("Apple"))
```

But it did not work.

Comment: "Reverse word function" is not enough for an explanation

Comment: Please explain... We're not mind readers, we're volunteers. What exactly are you expecting and what output are you getting vs what you want.

Comment: I want the Word Apple to print backwards Apple to elppA :)

Comment: You probably don't want to print the return value of `reversa` since it doesn't even have a `return` statement. It can only possibly print `None`

Comment: **First** of all str is a bad name it's a [builtin function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#str). **Second** just return string[::-1] that reverses the string

Answer (score 2):

Well there are existing functions for this already:

```
print("Apple"[::-1])
```

And:

```
print(''.join(reversed("Apple")))
```

Your code doesn't work because:

- since there's no `return` and only print, just call like: `reversa("Apple")`

Also, would be nice to `print()` at the end, like (fixed up some stuff):

```
def reversa(s):
    j=len(s)
    for i in s:
        j-=1
        print(str[j], end="")
    print()

print(reversa("Apple"))
```

Also if i where you, i would make a function like:

```
def reversa(s):
    return ''.join([s[-i] for i in range(1,len(s)+1)])
```

Which could be called like:

```
print(reversa('Apple'))
```

Comment: Damn, beat me again.

Comment: Flipped the coin on the wrong hand I guess

Comment: Lol, haha, :-) :D

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use range to increment backwards from the largest index position

```
def reversal(str):
    for i in range(len(str) - 1, -1, -1):
        print(str[i], end="")

reversal("Apple")
```

Answer (score -1):

The loop is not running one more time.

The thing is you are printing the function reversa (i.e. the return value of the function). Since you don't make the function return anything, None will be returned and printed after your function has ended.

You just need to call the function without print: `reversa("Apple")`